# C# WCF service for chat - SOAP or REST vs SignalR

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, soap

I'm planning to develop chat application in C# using WCF. I've read about SOAP and REST services that SOAP services are "heavier" but they provide security and REST ones do not. I've recently saw the new SignalR libary for real-time client-server communication and it seems to be much easier to code and understand. I think WCF would be a better choice for the moment, but I don't know SOAP or REST would be most appropriate for my case. Thanks in advance for any help provided! :)

Comment: This question doesn't describe any particular issue you have and therefore will be closed soon. Anyways why do you want to use WCF for a chat application if you already found out that SignalR does 99% of the job you need and is way easier to develop/integrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some remarks that I think would clarify things for you, before giving you an answer.

1. Both REST and SOAP are web service protocols playing over HTTP. **None of them is better from a security prespective.** SOAP web services definition include some **optional** security settings but this should not make you believe that a SOAP service is by definition more secure than a REST service.
2. SOAP wraps everything inside an XML envelope which imposes some traffic overhead. This is why SOAP is considered worse in performance but more formal and therefore more suitable for certain uses.
3. Both SOAP and REST are independent of the platform they are implemented. Usually, when someone writes in .NET, [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used to deploy them.
4. [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is **Microsoft specific technology** which actually simplifies and actually **wraps** the [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) provided by HTML5. It is ideal for someone who writes interactive web applications using transparent two-way communication. SignalR maximizes its benefit on scenarios of a server **pushing** data to browser.

Therefore, I would suggest doing some more reading for the specific technologies before selecting the appropriate for your case. I am not familiar with your project requirements but it sounds like the **SignalR** is the way for you to go, since a chatting application would definitely use real time two-way communication with the server, including the server **pushing** data to the client

Hope I helped!

Comment: *SignalR is **Microsoft specific technology*** this is completely wrong. Has nothing to-do with MS, MS just implemented a SignalR client&server for .Net...

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, guys! I'm certainly going to read more about the technologies, I just needed some information where to start from and I think SignalR is really the best choice for me now! :)

Comment: @MichaC With no intention to argue, I have never seen another implementation of SignalR. I have only seen [ASP.NET SignalR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR). If you can point me to some other implementation of SignaR I would gladly make the correction...